# Want to know why i am getting seg fault

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

I have this code where i am trying to create many data structures based on the input, "gen" entered by the user. here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;
struct rootset {
  double totSize;
  const char *rStrtPtr;
  const char *rEndPtr;

  struct generations {
    double totSize;
    const char *genStrtPtr;
    const char *genEndPtr; 
    int numOfGen;
    string genName;

    struct object {
      double objSize;
      const char *objStrtPtr;
      const char *objEndPtr;
      string id;
      char markBit;
      char objPtr;


      struct freeList {
    double freeSpace;
    int flNumb; 
      };
    };
  };
};

int main()
{

  int gen =0;
  cin >> gen;
  cin >> pmemSize;

  vector<rootset> pRootSet;
  pRootSet.push_back(rootset());
  pRootSet[0].totSize = pmemSize;

   vector <rootset::generations> generation;
   generation.push_back(rootset::generations());

  for( i=0; i<gen; i++) {
    stringstream out;
    out << i;
   string s = out.str();
   generation[i].genName = "generation" + s
   cout<<"gen name: "<<generation[i].genName<<endl;

  }
}
```

This code is printing:

```
3
50
gen name: generation0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But in my output i want it to create:

```
gen name: generation0
gen name: generation1
gen name: generation2
gen name: generation3
```

Please do let me know what is wrong with my code

Comment: Please post the complete program. I don't see the type of `pRootSet`. (assume it is `std::vector<rootset>`. Also check, if `generation[i]` is a valid index.

Comment: try using a debugger, it will tell you a bit more about the place where seg fault happens.

Comment: made my edits. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing `generation` out of bounds. It has size 1 by the time you enter the loop, so the loop could only work for `gen` equal to 0 or 1.

```
vector <rootset::generations> generation;
generation.push_back(rootset::generations()); // size = 1

for( i=0; i<gen; i++) {
  ...
  generation[i].genName = "generation" + s         // what is i?
  cout<<"gen name: "<<generation[i].genName<<endl; //  what is i?
```

Comment: i is the number of generations entered by the user. I guess i am not allowed to do it like that then.

Comment: How do i create multiple structures of generations then?

Comment: just move this line `generation.push_back(rootset::generations());` down so it is included inside the `for` loop

Comment: here generations is entered by user and is passed in through gen identifier

Comment: Thank you Arthur, That answered my question. I will mark the above code as answered.